# How can I get correct keywords count by Adwords v201502

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I use googleads-python-lib's example code in `examples/adwords/v201502/optimization/get_keyword_ideas.py`. However, the output information are kind of strange. Like this. I search for `water`, and one of the output is,

```
Keyword with 'water edea0831' text and average monthly search volume '-637139213815812803' was found with Products and Services categories: [33, 45, 47].
```

First, the keyword text `water edea0831` seems like a hex format but has no real mean. Second, the volume is negative!

I've tried many keyword and many search parameter and also googled for that, but still have no idea. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and I'm sorry for my bad description of my question.

Since I recognize my `testing account` as a temporary account for API user, I did ever never think that I can not get `real data` from google! I googled `red herring` which keyword repeatedly posted and found someone had the same problem three years ago. I will apply a formal account and I think that will work fine.

Thx for all.